# session request won't hold form data

Tags: python, session, python-requests

```
def login(email, password):
    payload = {'form_type':'customer_login', 'customer[email]': email, 
   'customer[password]': password}
    session = requests.Session()
    session.post('http://kith.com/account/login', data=payload, headers=
    {"Referer": "https://kith.com"})
    r = session.get('http://kith.com/account')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

    print(soup.prettify())
login(email, password)
```

Hello. Can anyone please assist? I am having trouble getting my account to login. Just getting familiar with the requests module and I am not sure what is going on. my email and password are correct and the headers. post data are correct as well. Here is some more code that works(shown below). Just wondering why the above code does not log me in though.

```
def login():
with requests.Session() as c:
    url = ('https://kith.com/account/login')
    Username = '<email address here>'
    Password = '<password here>'
    c.get(url)
    DATA = {'form_type':'customer_login','customer[email]':Username,'customer[password]':Password, }
    c.post(url, data=DATA, headers={"Referer": "https://kith.com"})
    page = c.get('https://kith.com/account')
    print(page.content)
```

login()

Comment: You’re posting to http:// not https. Maybe the request is failing from the server end?

Comment: you have to establish a session with a get request before you can post any data. ty tho